# Why does root multiplicity change the factors in partial fractions and homogenous differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-fractions

Why does a root with multiplicity larger than one generate different terms in partial fraction expansions and in finding the solution of homogeneous linear differential equations?

For example, consider the following expansion:

$$\frac{1}{s^2 - 4s + 4} = \frac{A}{s - 2} + \frac{B}{(s - 2)^2}$$

I can see why the denominators in the terms must be different, but not where the exponent comes from. I was taught this as "truth", but I don't know how to get there myself, or how to get a general formula.

The same is true for:

$$y'' - 4y' + 4y = 0$$

Leading to a general solution:

$$c_1 e^{2t} + c_2 te^{2t}$$

I don't know how the t appears and how what to do if the root's multiplicity was 3 (for example).

Comment: For $3$, as in $y'''-2y''+4y'-8y=0$, use $c_1e^{2t}+c_2te^{2t}+c_3t^2e^{2t}$.

Comment: The partial fraction decomposition is "explained", for example, when you learn about Laurent series in complex analysis, or residues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the nice comments eluded to, partial fractions are wrapped up in the Residue Theorem and Laurent Series.

Every function of the form $\displaystyle \frac{f(s)}{g(s)}$, where $f(s)$ and $g(s)$ are polynomials in $s$, can be reduced into the sum of fractions such that the denominator of each new fraction is either first degree or a quadratic polynomial raised to some power.

To each factor $g(s)$ of the form $(s-a)^m~$, assign a sum of $m$ fractions, of the form:

$$\displaystyle \frac{A_1}{s-a} + \frac{A_2}{(s-a)^2}+\cdots + \frac{A_m}{(s-a)^m}$$

To each factor, $g(s)$ of the form $(s^2+bs+c)^p$, assign a sum of partial fractions, of the form:

$$\displaystyle \frac{B_1s+C_1}{(s^2+bs+c)^1} + \frac{B_2s+C_2}{(s^2+bs+c)^2} + \cdots + \frac{B_ps + C_p}{(s^2+bs+c)^p}$$

where $A_i, B_j$ and $C_k ~(i=1, 2, \ldots, m;~j, k= 1, 2, \ldots , p)$ are constants which must be determined.

Set the original fraction, $\displaystyle \frac{f(s)}{g(s)}$, equal to the sum of the new fractions from above. Clear the resulting equation of fractions, and then equate coefficients of like powers of $s$, thereby resulting in a set of simultaneous linear equations in the unknown constants $A_i, B_j$ and $C_k$. Finally, solve for these $A_i, B_j$ and $C_k$.

**Theory**

- [*Residue Theorem - Residue Calculus*](http://math.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/ResidueCalcMod.html)
- [*Residue and Laurent*](http://samples.jbpub.com/9781449604455/04455_CH08_Mathews.pdf)
- [*Residue Method for Partial Fractions Decomposition*](http://www.math.vt.edu/people/dlr/m2k_opm_lappf2.pdf)

**Useful Resources**

- [*Nice little step-by-step JavaScript*](http://calc101.com/webMathematica/partial-fractions.jsp)
- [*Wiki Partial Fractions*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction)
- [*Partial fractions decomposition - Methods Survey*](http://math.feld.cvut.cz/mt/txtd/3/txe3db3i.htm)

Comment: You're really helpful, through and through! +1