# Partial fractions trick, repeated roots

Tags: residue-calculus, partial-fractions

Do you know how can one extend [this trick to find partial fractions coefficients](https://medium.com/@mathphye/math-trick-partial-fraction-decomposition-case-1-33c0e0a54945) when the roots of the denominator are repeated? From now, I'm just interested in the cases when the roots are algebraic.

Comment: The magic words are [Heaviside cover-up method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method).

Comment: P.S. Roots are *always* algebraic. Did you mean "real"?

Comment: Yep, algebraic over $\mathbb{R}$ ***

Comment: "algebraic over $\mathbb{R}$" means "real or complex"... The proviso still sounds rather nonsensical to me.

Comment: Sure, rinse and repeat; decompose $\dfrac1{(x-a)(x-b)}$, then divide by $(x-b)$ and reuse the previous decomposition.$$\frac1{(x-a)(x-b)}=\frac1{a-b}\left(\frac1{x-a}-\frac1{x-b}\right) \implies \frac1{(x-a)(x-b)^2}=\cdots$$

Comment: Refer to this excellent answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/332328/1209152

Answer (score 4):

I remember seeing a method for this in generatingfunctionology which I found interesting. You do the same idea of substituting convenient values of $x$, but when you have higher order terms, you can also take the derivative. For example, with
$$\frac{x^2+1}{(x-1)^2(x+1)^2}=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{C}{x+1}+\frac{D}{(x+1)^2}$$
we want to solve for $A,B,C,D$ in the polynomial equation
$$x^2+1=A(x-1)(x+1)^2+B(x+1)^2+C(x-1)^2(x+1)+D(x-1)^2$$
Plugging in $x=1$ and $x=-1$ gives the following equations respectively
$$2=4B$$
$$2=4D$$
Now to solve for $A,C$ we can take the derivative and then plug in $x=1$ and $x=-1$.
$$2x=2A(x-1)(x+1)+A(x+1)^2+2B(x+1)+2C(x-1)(x+1)+C(x-1)^2+2D(x-1)$$
We get the following equations
$$2=4A+4B$$
$$-2=4C-4D$$
Solving gives $A,C=0$ and $B=D=\frac{1}{2}$.
I guess this wasn't the most exciting example, but you can see that the method works and all the substitutions are still convenient ones that cancel a lot of terms. And maybe you will complain that when taking the derivative, you have to write out a lot more terms. But notice that with some foresight multiple terms will be $0$ in all cases so you can strategically skip writing those out.

Comment: This is good. It can be improved by noting that derivatives of polynomials, say $f'(a)$ is the same as the quotient of $f(x)$ after division by $x-a$, evaluated at $x=a$, and that both that quotient and its evaluation are a byproduct of using Ruffini-Horner to evaluate $f(a)$.

Comment: @NDB I see, this is what you meant by your comment in the OP I presume. I was having a bit trouble following that approach. Is the $f$ in your comment referring to $x^2+1$?

Comment: One of them. The coefficients to write $x^2+1=a_0+a_1(x-1)+a_2(x-1)^2$ can be obtained by successive evaluation of the left at $x=1$ (gives $a_0$) If this evaluation is done using Ruffini-Horner, a byproduct is the quotient by $x-1$. But the quotient is also $a_1+a_2(x-1)$. So, $a_1$ can again be found by just doing Ruffini again.

Comment: The use of Ruffini-Horner is just an efficient way to write $\frac{x^2+1}{(x+1)^2}=\frac{2+2(x-1)+(x-1)^2}{4+4(x-1)+(x-1)^2}$. Then doing long division with reverse degree monomial order (only two steps of the division in your example) one gets the first two coefficients $B+A(x-1)$. More steps, $n$, if the order of the pole $(x-1)$  is $n$, instead of $2$. Each step of the division pops one coefficient.

Comment: Would it not be faster to just substitute $y+1=x$?

Comment: Yes, that is what is done, but Ruffini-Horner is the way to do that efficiently. Note that in the example expanding $(x+1)^2+1$ is easy, but in a degree $6$ polynomial we don't want to expand the $(x+1)^6$, the $(x+1)^5$, the $(x+1)^4$, ... etc. and collect all the terms.